# How do wireless companies block mVoIP traffics?

Tags: sip, voip

I am a mVoIP developer and ready to launch a new mobile application. However, there is one tough problem in my country. In my country, wireless companies block mVoIp service by limiting internet data for mVoIP. They allow mVoIP traffic about 25mb-250mb a month.

It doesn't look like they are monitoring SIP(5060) port. I believe they check specific mVoIP service domain addresses and monitor wireless data traffics.

If it is true, is they a way to hide mVoIP traffic? (Maybe, I can change mVoIP server address randomly?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various different ways that a service provider can do this - for example:

- monitor and limit RTP traffic (the actual speech, rather than the SIP signalling)
- monitor SIP protocol traffic and limit new connections being set up
- block traffic to and from known servers that support VoIP

If you do try to work around whatever mechanism they are using, there is really nothing to stop them then targeting and dealing with the workaround if they really care about it - for instance they may have deep packet inspection capabilities which would identify the traffic profile and could probably quickly see server name changes. Doing this requires money, time and effort on the service providers part though so unless you are really eating into their revenue they usually won't bother.

Take a look at the answer here for some pointers on 'disguising' SIP signalling if that is really all you need (but again bear in mind that if you are wildly successful then they will just block your server anyway):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9033162/334402

The real trick is for your service or application not to be too successful...